# Is re-starting a Thread better than creating a new one?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I'm wondering whether there is any advantage to keeping the same threads over the course of the execution of an object, rather than re-using the same Thread objects. I have an object for which a single (frequently used) method is parallelized using local Thread variables, such that every time the method is called, new Threads (and Runnables) are instantiated. Because the method is called so frequently, a single execution may instantiate upwards of a hundred thousand Thread objects, even though there are never more than a few (~4-6) active at any given time.

Following is a cut down example of how this method is currently implemented, to give a sense of what I mean. For reference, `n` is of course the pre-determined number of threads to use, whereas `this.dataStructure` is a (thread-safe) `Map` which serves as the input to the computation, as well as being modified by the computation. There are other inputs involved, but as they are not relevant to this question, I've omitted their usage. I've also omitted exception handling for the same reason.

```
Runnable[] tasks = new Runnable[n];
Thread[] threads = new Thread[n];
ArrayBlockingQueue<MyObject> inputs = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(this.dataStructure.size());
inputs.addAll(this.dataStructure.values());

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tasks[i] = () -> {
        while (true) {
            MyObject input = inputs.poll(1L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
            if (input == null) return;
            // run computations over this.dataStructure
        }
    };
    threads[i] = new Thread(tasks[i]);
    threads[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    threads[i].join();
```

Because these Threads (and their runnables) always execute the same way using a single ArrayBlockingQueue as input, an alternative to this would be to just "refill the queue" every time the method is called and just re-start the same Threads. This is easily implemented, but I'm unsure as to whether it would make any difference one way or the other. I'm not too familiar with concurrency, so any help is appreciated.

PS.: If there is a more elegant way to handle the polling, that would also be helpful.

Comment: You probably want [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync%28java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.Executor%29)s

Comment: How do you avoid an endless loop with your `while (true) {` code? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your `this.dataStructure` map changing? Or is it a fixed quantity of inputs to be consumed fully by this code here?

Comment: I am confused by `// run computations over this.dataStructure`. Your loop is processing individual `MyObject` objects, one at a time, each taken from your `Map<MyObject>` title `this.dataStructure`, accessed via the `ArrayBlockingQueue`. So why does this comment refer to going back over that `this.dataStructure` map of `MyObject` objects?

Comment: To clarify, because the queue is only input to once and never gets added to during the execution of the threads, eventually the result of polling will be null, which terminates the loop. Also, my apologies for the lack of clarity in exactly what this does: this.dataStructure is in actuality a matrix, its entries being a row index and a Map for the row itself. What the computations do is fill out those rows, but they do not actually add to or remove from the existing set of rows. This is why the iteration works; the objects being iterated over may be modified, but their location is not.

Comment: I suspect your work could be much simpler and much more performant with the new concurrency features of *Project Loom* being incubated and previewed in Java 19. I tried to start writing some example code but despite a dozen readings  of your Question I cannot get a handle on your data and operations. My gut tells me the queue is a distraction, and likely unnecessary. This kind of question could be much improved with a contrived example of concrete data structures containing concrete data samples.

Comment: FYI, [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main), [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425), and [structured concurrency](https://openjdk.org/jeps/428).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to start a Thread more than once, but conceptually, the answer to your question is yes.

This is normally accomplished with a thread pool.  A thread pool is a set of Threads which rarely actually terminate.  Instead, an application is passes its task to the thread pool, which picks a Thread in which to run it.  The thread pool then decides whether the Thread should be terminated or reused after the task completes.

Java has some classes which make use of thread pools quite easy:  [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

ExecutorService usage typically looks like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tasks[i] = () -> {
        while (true) {
            MyObject input = inputs.poll(1L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
            if (input == null) return;
            // run computations over this.dataStructure
        }
    };
    executor.submit(tasks[i]);
}

// Doesn't interrupt or halt any tasks.  Will wait for them all to finish
// before terminating its threads.
executor.shutdown();

executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

`Executors` has other methods which can create thread pools, like [newFixedThreadPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) and [newWorkStealingPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool()).  You can decide for yourself which one best suits your needs.

CompletableFuture use might look like this:

```
Runnable[] tasks = new Runnable[n];
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = new CompletableFuture<?>[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tasks[i] = () -> {
        while (true) {
            MyObject input = inputs.poll(1L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
            if (input == null) return;
            // run computations over this.dataStructure
        }
    };
    futures[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(tasks[i]);
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).get();
```

The disadvantage of CompletableFuture is that the tasks cannot be canceled or interrupted.  (Calling `cancel` will mark the task as completing with an exception instead of completing successfully, but the task will not be interrupted.)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response! As I mentioned, I am not familiar with concurrency in general, let alone the concurrency resources in Java, so this is extremely helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

Per definition, you cannot restart a thread. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):
*It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.*

Nevertheless a thread is a valuable resource, and there are implementations to reuse threads. Have a look at the [Java Tutorial about Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).